# AC current measurement - input protection circuit

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, analog, adc, circuit-protection

[image: AC measurement with CT - Input circuit]
Hi  there

I am developing a AC current measurement device based on Current  transformer.
I was taking a look to many questions related with this subject  but in this case I would need some help
regarding the microcontroller chip input circuitry. As you can see from the attached schematics Fig.1 and fig. 2 were taken from other questions, so these ones inspired me partially to implement the input protection for my circuit. As reference I am using a SOC chip MCU,  precisely PSoC 5LP from Cypress.
As  CT, I am using 2000:1-  30 A/15 ma  -  R burden :10 ohm.
The following link is the data sheet for the CT.
  (https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Current/ECS1030-L72-SPEC.pdf )

In fig 3 ( dash lines are a issue I have with the editor), I'm showing  a resistor divider 560k / 560k and  a couple of capacitors for decoupling the central point of the voltage divider.

*My question is regarding the value that should have the resistor R_4 that limit the current after the burden resistor_3.*

Looking at the PSoC 5LP data sheet regarding the absolute maximum ratings for a input pin, in this case is the OP-AmP_1 input,  the min current should be -30 ma  and max  should be  41 ma. 
The maximum input voltage for the pin should be  3.3 V + 0.5 V.  I'm using one of two option 3.3v or 5V as VDD.
I would like some hint about how calculate that  resistor value.

*My other question is if 1N4148 can protect  the input , I am not sure . Should I use Shottky diodes?*

Thank you very much for some  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those currents the burden voltage is in the +0.5 to -0.5V range resulting in an input voltage between 1V - 2V. If the current exceeds those limits you want a clamping device with a forward voltage of less than 0.5V, so the 1N4148 wont work. Shottky diodes have a lower forward voltage. Use R4 to limit the current flowing trough the clamping device. Look at the V-I plot of a diode to determine at which current you get the desired forward voltage.

Comment: Thank you, can you clarify how you get +5 to -0.5 burden voltage?

Comment: Not exactly +-0.5V. Ohms law and KCL.